# How to get reference to running service?

Tags: java, android

There is a one problem - my main activity starts the service and be closed then. When the application starts next time the application should get reference to this service and stop it. But I don't know how I can get a reference to a running service. Please, I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if ("your.service.classname".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

if(isMyServiceRunning()) {
    stopService(new Intent(ServiceTest.this,MailService.class));
}
```

Comment: but how can I stop the service using your example?

Comment: Uhm .. that's pretty superfluous. Just call `stopService` regardless of whether your `Service` is running or not - there's no harm if it isn't - `stopService` will just return `false`.

Comment: Your example is wrong.  The return values need swapped.

Comment: ActivityManager should be used for testing and debugging purposes only. (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html)

Answer (score 10):

This answer is based on the [answer by @DawidSajdak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10482276/1232833). His code is mostly correct, but he switched the `return` statements, so it gives the opposite of the intended result. The correct code should be:

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if ("your.service.classname".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true; // Package name matches, our service is running
        }
    }
    return false; // No matching package name found => Our service is not running
}

if(isMyServiceRunning()) {
    stopService(new Intent(ServiceTest.this,MailService.class));
}
```

Comment: this is just checking the service is running or not can I get the instance of the service

Comment: @avezRaj I didn't try this, but I would assume that "service" will contain a reference to the service once the if condition is true.

Comment: service does not contain reference of Service object. it gives an error of incompatable types

Comment: In that case, I don't know.